# Why does my streaming command fail for MapReduce basic program?

Tags: ruby, streaming, hadoop, cloudera

I was trying to run a Ruby Hadoop streaming program, which is given in "Definitive guide for Ruby".

This is the command I used:

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-0.20.2+737.jar 
-input input/temperature -output output -mapper /home/cloudera/projects/max_temp/map.rb 
-reducer /home/cloudera/projects/max_temp/reduce.rb
```

The file paths are right. Once I run the command, I get an error like this:

```
packageJobJar: [/var/lib/hadoop-0.20/cache/cloudera/hadoop-unjar7505856816337735719/] [] /tmp/streamjob5440613434295562761.jar tmpDir=null
11/03/14 22:58:56 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
11/03/14 22:58:56 INFO streaming.StreamJob: getLocalDirs(): [/var/lib/hadoop-0.20/cache/cloudera/mapred/local]
11/03/14 22:58:56 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Running job: job_201103140235_0015
11/03/14 22:58:56 INFO streaming.StreamJob: To kill this job, run:
11/03/14 22:58:56 INFO streaming.StreamJob: /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/bin/hadoop job -Dmapred.job.tracker=localhost:8021 -kill job_201103140235_0015
11/03/14 22:58:56 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Tracking URL: http://localhost:50030/jobdetails.jsp...
11/03/14 22:58:57 INFO streaming.StreamJob: map 0% reduce 0%
11/03/14 22:59:54 INFO streaming.StreamJob: map 100% reduce 100%
11/03/14 22:59:54 INFO streaming.StreamJob: To kill this job, run:
11/03/14 22:59:54 INFO streaming.StreamJob: /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/bin/hadoop job -Dmapred.job.tracker=localhost:8021 -kill job_201103140235_0015
11/03/14 22:59:54 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Tracking URL: http://localhost:50030/jobdetails.jsp...
11/03/14 22:59:54 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not Successful!
11/03/14 22:59:54 INFO streaming.StreamJob: killJob...
Streaming Command Failed!
```

I looked in the map log file, and this is the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:379)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:317)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1063)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:211)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:34)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:230)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/cloudera/projects/max_temp/map.rb": java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:214)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:148)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:65)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
... 24 more
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Lev Khomich for your reply. I have fixed this issue by mentioning file parameter in the command:

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-0.20.2+737.jar \
-input input/temperature -output output -mapper /home/cloudera/projects/max_temp/map.rb \
-reducer /home/cloudera/projects/max_temp/reduce.rb \
-file /home/cloudera/projects/words/map.rb \
-file /home/cloudera/projects/words/reduce.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error with you, and fixed problem by copy 'map.rb' and 'reduce.rb' files to /tmp/, then run it with parms as `-mapper /tmp/map.rb -reducer /tmp/reduce.rb`